# WindowsForm application crashes on InitializeComponent

Tags: c#, windows-xp, crash

My relatively simple Window Application seems to crash as soon as it gets to the InitializeComponent method in the form's constructor. Now the form is obviously a partial class and InitializeComponent is call to the method in the other part of the partial class.
Problem is that other partial class is generated. How do I go about debugging it and finding out which line is causing my app to crash. The application crashes with an error report dialog with very sparse details of the error. I cant debug the app through the IDE because the application only crashes on the deployment machine and loading vs2008 on that machine is out of the question. Please help.

Comment: what does the exception says?

Comment: I dont get an exception or at least I cant see one. I get one of those "Please tell Microsoft about this problem" dialog boxes. The error report itself contains mostly noise and a hex dump. Modules mentioned are mscorlib and other than that its just one huge amount of data in the error report of modules in use and their version numbers etc. That's why I'm so frustrated. Theres nothing good in it.

Comment: One a side note. I have wrapped everything in the form constructor in a try catch like so: try { do stuff } catch(Exception e) {MessageBox.Show(e.Message)} but the exception is never thrown. Just the MS Report this bla bla box.

Comment: Is remote debugging an option? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Comment: maybe, would have to twist a network admins arm first

Comment: Ok, here is an interesting development. I created a blank windows form application called Test. Works perfectly on my dev machine. copied over the binaries to the machine in question here and I get the same result. At least that rules out a lot of other issues like funky libraries and stuff. I'm starting to wonder if the .NET install on this box isn't corrupt or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details it will be difficult to give you any specific suggestions.

You might add an event handler to the [application ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) to catch any unhandled exceptions.  In the event handler I would log the exception, stacktrace, and any other relevant data you might have.  If you are not using a logging framework of some kind then you can always use what's available in the System.Diagnostics namespace (and the necessary additions to your app.config) in order to add some simple log output handling.

The other thought I have is are you using non-MS provided UI libraries?  If so, are they included with your application/installer.  Assuming your app uses some and they aren't included this could be the reason why it crashed in the InitializeComponent call.

**Update:**
Based upon your comments I've updated my answer.  You can add code to the InitializeComponent method, just keep in mind it's generated code so editing it does pose some risk.  Dumb question but have you checked to make sure the constructor is even being called?  The fact that it's crashing the way you describe is typically an indicator that something fundamental to the app is missing/configured incorrectly on the target machine.  You might also check the Windows Event Log on that machine to see if anything useful was entered there for you.

Comment: Nope, doesn't trigger the event. Pity I cant just modify the partial classe's InitializeComponent method with a few MessageBox.Shows

Comment: For what it's worth, in my experience, a crash that doesn't trigger ThreadException is usually one of two things: it's either a stack overflow, or an exception in a finalizer.

Comment: Had a look at the event log
It contains the following info:
EventID: 5000

EventType clr20r3, P1 tombopoc.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4d468dd5, P4 mscorlib, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4be90358, P7 20a2, P8 7, P9 n3ctrye2kn3c34sgl4zqyrbfte4m13nb, P10 NIL.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Comment: Mmm, I assumed that you could not edit the generated code because with every build it would just get overwritten. Based on your update I gave it a go and littered the InitliazeComponent with a dozen or so MessageBox.Show("#1") lines and eventuall tracked down the culprit: this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));

This line was trying to load the icon resource. Not really sure why it could not load it on that specific machine but I just replaced the icon and bobs your uncle, everything works. Hate those tiny things that wasted what 3 hours now???

Comment: Definitely not the preferred way to track down the problem, but sometimes you just need to brute force it.

Answer (score 1):

ThreadException does work here yet, the exception is raised too early.  Write an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, subscribe it in your Main() method (Program.cs) before the Application.Run() and/or form constructor call.  In the event handler log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  The exception message and the stack trace you'll get is almost always good enough to diagnose and correct the cause of the exception.

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, giving this a go. I've even wacked all my controls on the form to get rid of code in the InitializeComponent section. No luck yet, but let me try your suggestion quick.

Comment: There is no reasonable failure mode for this, other than getting the event subscription wrong.  Post updated with code sample.

Comment: In Program.cs main, first line:

    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);


And then offcourse:

 static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        }

Comment: Yep, that's what I had. I'm still just as dumbfounded but have a look at the comments on confusedGeek's answer of how the problem was solved. Messy I know, I should have a logging framework, but this is a tinnnnny app.